# trouble with CiviCRM Installer on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, installation, configuration

I am trying to setup CiviCRM 4.7 on most recent Wordpress -- copied the folder to /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins/ and was able to see the plugins in Wordpress.

When I click on "configure CiviCRM", it takes me to a blank page -- there are no options available.

I am using Apache2, PHP, MariaDB on CentOS 7

Comment: Did you run the installer? What is the name of the directory? Where did you copy the folder from? What did you click "configure CiviCRM" on? Thanks!

Comment: I unpacked the package -- didnt run the installer. 

It was under "/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm"

When I click "configure CiviCRM" on wordpress it showed me a blank wordpress page with no options, no messages, nothing.

At the moment, I deleted the 4.7 version and trying to use 4.5.1 version civiCRM and that has only mysql files and language packs (source: SourceForge)

Comment: Are you logged in as admin?

Answer (score 1):

CiviCRM is a very different beast than other plugins - it has more code than WordPress itself!  Unfortunately the "normal" WordPress installation doesn't work.  You can find detailed instructions here: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Installing+CiviCRM+for+WordPress.  Also feel free to ask both here and on https://chat.civicrm.org for help!